# desarrollo de paquetes secuenciales en php

Tags: php, composer, packages

Anteriormente he desarrollado un paquete en php para la detección de environment:

https://github.com/arcanisgk/WEB-CLI-Detector

una vez que ya lo he publicando pase a desarrollar otro paquete en el cual quiero implementar el anterior:

mi nuevo `composer.json` donde `arcanisgk/web-cli-detector` es requerido, luce así :

```json
{
  "name": "arcanisgk/beh-basic-error-handler",
  "description": "*[BEH]* is a very simple PHP [error handler] implementation that throws\n[ErrorException] exceptions instead of using the default PHP error handling\nbehaviour. This means that all runtime errors including Fatal are presented to the\ndeveloper in the form of an exception. It also means that any unhandled errors\nare delivered to a single point: the global exception handler.\nalso includes support for login errors with [error document]",
  "type": "library",
  "license": "MIT",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "IcarosNet\\BasicErrorHandler\\": "src/"
    },
    "files": [
      "src/checkErrorEngineInstallation.php"
    ]
  },
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Walter Nuñez",
      "email": "icarosnet@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.4",
    "arcanisgk/web-cli-detector": "^1.0",
    "ext-json": "*"
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true
  }
}
```

hasta este punto todo bien:

- se instalaron las dependencias.
- se ejecuta el archivo de validación: checkErrorEngineInstallation.php

y mi `index.php` luce así:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

require_once __DIR__."/../vendor/autoload.php";
```

el problema ocurre al desarrollar esta clase `ErrorEngine`:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace IcarosNet\BasicErrorHandler;

use IcarosNet\WebCLIDetector\WebCLIDetector;

class ErrorEngine
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */

    private string $line_separator;

    /**
     * @var ErrorEngine|null
     */

    private static ?ErrorEngine $instance = null;

    /**
     * @return ErrorEngine
     */

    public static function getInstance(): ErrorEngine
    {
        if (!self::$instance instanceof self) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * this class is armed automatically at the moment it is instantiated and remains active.
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setLineSeparator($this->detectLineSeparator());
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */

    public function getLineSeparator(): string
    {
        return $this->line_separator;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $line_separator
     */

    public function setLineSeparator(string $line_separator): void
    {
        $this->line_separator = $line_separator;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */

    private function detectLineSeparator(): string
    {

        $detector = new WebCLIDetector();

        return $detector->isCLI() ? PHP_EOL : '<br>';
    }

}

ErrorEngine::getInstance();
```

al llegar a la linea esta:

```
$detector = new WebCLIDetector();
```

me retorna este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
> 'IcarosNet\WebCLIDetector\WebCLIDetector' not found in
> D:\Desarrollos\Personales\Web\BEH-Basic-Error-Handler\src\ErrorEngine.php:86
> Stack trace:
> #0 D:\Desarrollos\Personales\Web\BEH-Basic-Error-Handler\src\ErrorEngine.php(59):
> IcarosNet\BasicErrorHandler\ErrorEngine->detectLineSeparator()
> #1 D:\Desarrollos\Personales\Web\BEH-Basic-Error-Handler\src\ErrorEngine.php(47):
> IcarosNet\BasicErrorHandler\ErrorEngine->__construct()
> #2 D:\Desarrollos\Personales\Web\BEH-Basic-Error-Handler\src\ErrorEngine.php(93):
> IcarosNet\BasicErrorHandler\ErrorEngine::getInstance()
> #3 {main} thrown in D:\Desarrollos\Personales\Web\BEH-Basic-Error-Handler\src\ErrorEngine.php
> on line 86

al parecer solo si dentro del método hago nuevamente el `require`, entonces funciona:

```php
    private function detectLineSeparator(): string
    {
        require_once __DIR__."/../vendor/autoload.php";

        $detector = new WebCLIDetector();

        return $detector->isCLI() ? PHP_EOL : '<br>';
    }
```

no me queda clara por que, suponía que no tendría que volver a hacer `require`

Comment: Por lo que tengo entendido `Include_once` y `Require_once` evitan que el archivo se vuelva a incluir si ya fue incluido anteriormente, si está incluido con una sentencia `Require_once` inicialmente, debería funcionar dentro del ámbito de la función, con lo cual repetir la línea de `Require_once` no debería modificar nada... o me equivoco?

Comment: @Liyo es lo mismo que pensaba yo... pero el escenario que describo es lo que he tenido que hacer para hacerlo funcionar ...

Comment: Lo solucionaste?

Comment: si, hahahahhahavahhahaha